# Exported java project shown wrongly on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, user-interface, jcomponent

i got a little problem: I exported a project on eclipse as a Runnable jar file. Eclipse is installed on windows and the jar works on windows perfectly. When i put the jar on a stick and drag it to my Mac the JComponents of my GUI are not shown anymore. I work with layout managers. Does anybody have an idea how i can fix that problem?
Thanks:)

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: No it surrounded the Main code with try and catch - no error message

Comment: do you have the same java versions on both machines?